# How to combine two queries so result of one query will be using in another query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can use results of one query in another query?

I need something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    orderDate,
    goodsCount = (
            SELECT
                    count(*) as Count
            FROM 
                    ShopOrderGoods
            WHERE 
                    order_id = so.id
    )
FROM 
    ShopOrders
```

ShopOrder is a table, where I store orders. ShopOrderGoods is a table where I store goods of each order.

I can do this with server language + 2 (if only 1 row in ShopOrders table) queries.

I do first query:

```
select * from ShopOrders
```

In server language I am working with results of this query:

```
$rowset = $resultOfQuery;
foreach($rowset as $order) {
    // do another query: select count(*) as Count from ShopOrderGoods where order_id = $order->id;
    // put result to $count variable
    // output $order->orderDate, $order->id, $count
}
```

So I will make 1 + N queries (N is number of rows in ShopOrder table) — not good at all.

So I want to do that using only 1 query. Expected result is:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + orderDate  + count +
+ 1  + 2014-12-12 + 15    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  + 2014-11-11 + 10    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 2010-10-10 + 8     +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

It is not neccessary to do it for me! Maybe you can say what I should type in google. Thank you.

### Update

Is it possible to add summ price of all goods of this order to the result set? Price of each table is storing in another table - `SuppliersGoods`.

Expected result set is:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + orderDate  + count +  sum +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 2014-12-12 + 15    + 7500  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  + 2014-11-11 + 10    + 3000  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 2010-10-10 + 8     + 2000  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In table SuppliersGoods price is stored in field `price`. Good count is specified in table `ShopOrderGoods` as field `count`.

### Update 2

SQL I have tried (works):

```
SELECT 
    so.id,
    so.orderDate,
    s.name as supplierName,
    COUNT(*) as goodsCount,
    SUM(sg.price*sop.count) as goodsSum
FROM 
    ShopOrders as so
INNER JOIN
    Contracts as c
    ON c.id = so.contract_id
INNER JOIN 
    Suppliers as s
    ON s.id = c.supplier_id 
INNER JOIN 
    ShopOrderGoods as sop
    ON sop.shopOrder_id = so.id
INNER JOIN 
    SuppliersGoods as sg
    ON sop.supplierGood_id = sg.id 
GROUP BY
    so.id, so.orderDate, s.name
```

Is it good? Looks monstrous a bit :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a nested query is necessary; an [`inner join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) with a [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) should be enough.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    so.id,
    so.orderDate,
    COUNT(sog.id) AS goodsCount
FROM 
    ShopOrders so
INNER JOIN 
    ShopOrderGoods sog
ON 
    sog.order_id = so.id
GROUP BY
    so.id, so.orderDate
```

---

**Update** try something like this to get the total price of each order (I'm guessing the column names):

```
SELECT 
    so.id,
    so.orderDate,
    COUNT(sog.id) AS goodsCount,
    SUM(sg.price * sog.count) AS sum
FROM 
    ShopOrders so
INNER JOIN 
    ShopOrderGoods sog
ON 
    sog.order_id = so.id
INNER JOIN 
    SupplierGoods sg
ON 
    sog.good_id = sg.id
GROUP BY
    so.id, so.orderDate
```

Comment: Yes it works. If I select not 2 + count, but 10 + count fields, should I specify all 10 fields in `group by`?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav That's correct. If you want to pull back the distinct values of a column, you need to put it in the `group by` clause. Otherwise, you can only use it as part of an aggregate function (like `count`).

Comment: If all your columns is functionally dependent of id you can apply an aggregate like max(...) on each of them: `select id, max(c1), max(c2), ..., count(*) from ... group by id`. If soem of the columns are not f.d. of id you add them to the group by clause: select id, c1, max(c2), ..., count(*) from ... group by id, c1`

Comment: @p.s.w.g :) Thank you for your answer. Can you look to the update of my question? Just realized that I need to add summ price of all goods to each order. Is it possible? Don't understand how to do this with group by and join.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I was working on an updated answer but your second update with `supplierName` really threw me off. Are you trying to group the result by order or by supplier? How would you expect this result set to look if an order was placed with two different suppliers?

Comment: In the result set I want to get all orders with `count` (how many names of goods is in this order) and `sum` (how much does all items cost (all items, not only names))

Comment: @SharikovVladislav So really `supplierName` is not important in the result set? In that case, see my updated answer.

Comment: There are no problems with it. Look [this](http://i.gyazo.com/75d57e83985001691a75a2e4d7040ef6.png) — two orders from one supplier.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Well when you throw the `supplierName` into the `group by`, it means you want to put every order and supplier in a group then count / sum the goods from each group. In other words if a single order includes 2 item from Samsung and 2 item from Sony, you'll get two rows with count 2, and the sum will only be total price of the goods from each supplier. In other words, you won't know the total count or sum of the order as a whole.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55794/discussion-between-sharikov-vladislav-and-p-s-w-g).

Comment: Stop :) Forget about it :))) I am doing order from supplier, so it can't have two items from sony and two items from samsung. All items can be either sony or samsung. Its ok :)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav In that case, your solution should work. Glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a join:

```
SELECT id, orderDate, count(*) as goodsCount
FROM ShopOrders so
JOIN ShopOrderGoods sog
   ON sog.order_id = so.id
GROUP BY id, orderDate;
```